# Basic questions about Payday - The Heist

Tags: payday-the-heist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Payday: The Heist, how do you change which upgrade tree you're on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/in-payday-the-heist-how-do-you-change-which-upgrade-tree-youre-on)

Three friends and me have started playing Payday - The Heist. Unfortunately we have quite a hard time in "understanding" some of the basic mechanics in the game.
So my first question is :

Is there any new player guide to this game? Because if so, I have a hard time finding one

If not, then maybe you can answer some of these questions:

1. What exactly do I gain by destroying video cameras?
2. Are hostages any more than just Trade objects for my teammates in custody?
3. Are there different classes? If so , how do I change? If I press Tab and switch with 1,2 or 3 nothing actually happens.
4. Is there any system to the Police Assaults? -> How do they get triggered? After passing a specific checkpoint or after a specific time? If so, when is the timer resetted?
5. Do the assaults end due to a timer or a bodycount?

**Edit:**

I just want to make question 4 about the police assaults a bit more specific:

How do they get triggerted? This means - when will a police assault start? Does this depend on some kind of timer ( for example: a police assault will start every 5 minutes ) or does it depend on mewalking over a specific location (e.g. I pass a crossroad , which means now there will be a police assault incoming)?

Comment: Hi @Toby, all your questions have already been answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/in-payday-the-heist-how-do-you-change-which-upgrade-tree-youre-on), [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34096/what-determines-the-duration-of-the-assault-phase-in-payday-the-heist), [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53179/what-is-the-point-of-taking-hostages-in-payday) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40518/whats-the-exact-effect-of-the-security-cameras-in-first-world-bank). You can click a tag to see all questions for it in order to ->

Comment: search for questions that have already been asked. In addition, in the future, it would be preferred if you asked each question separately, as it makes it clearer for other people to find the question, and it also makes it easier for people to submit and vote on the best answers. If the assault question does not answer the question to your satisfaction, you can ask the answerer for more clarification in a comment or put a bounty on the question so it gets more attention.

Comment: "*What exactly do I gain by destroying video cameras?*" See: [What's the exact effect of the security cameras in First World Bank?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/406269/4797)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`What exactly do I gain by destroying video cameras?`
Police and assaults takes more time to reach you. Teorically, it lowers the cops intel on you.

Here is a text from [payday's wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/First_World_Bank_-_Walkthrough)

`Destroying the cameras will "Reduce police intel" on your team, which will make it harder for the police to group up and find your squad, as they are forced to spread out and search for you. More often than not, if you or your team is within viewing distance of a camera, they will home in on you directly.`

`Are hostages any more than just Trade objects for my teammates in custody?`

No, actually, no. Also, keeping civilians as hostages counts to a chalenge in which you have to do it a certain number of times (like 30 or so for level 1 chalenge).
Check [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53179/what-is-the-point-of-taking-hostages-in-payday) about hostages

`Are there different classes? If so , how do I change? If I press Tab and switch with 1,2 or 3 nothing actually happens.`

Leveling system in Payday the heist is a little tricky, but works like this:

1. You press TAB and pick between 1,2 or 3
2. Once you level, the currently selected "role" will earn its reward (be it a passive skill, a weapon, or a equipment).

No, you can't choose the reward you are going to earn, only the role to receive it's next reward uppon your level up.

Notice that there is no such thing as `class experience`, you can for instance, play assault until you are missing 1 xp to level (i mean overall level, not assault level) and them, switch to support, and shoot someone. (which will give you exp).
Doing this will result in you leveling your support tree and getting the reward of leveling its tree to level X.

The next reward and the reward you just unlocked for leveling up a role is always shown once you level up.

```
Is there any system to the Police Assaults?
```

Overall police assaults are triggered over time. The time between assaults changes in each difficulty.

If you stay at the same place for a while, without trigering any objective or moving, there will be more than 1 assault, which leads to the `time-triggered` assault theory.
Even tho i haven't found any source that confirms this, i have tried to stay in the same area without moving and there were more than 1 assault.

```
To the assautls end due to a timer or a bodycount?
```

Time slice. [check this out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34096/what-determines-the-duration-of-the-assault-phase-in-payday-the-heist)

Comment: Hey Marcello, thanks for your answer. I updated my question number 4. About the levelling System: Does that mean I just chose which Class I level now? Does this affect the challenges I have to do? Or is it just that all my XP I get at this point are counted towards that class? But regardless of the class I can equip my self with the unlocked items from every class?

Comment: @Toby Edited my answer to make it cleared. I hope it helps you.
I can't answer your number 3 question, sorry.

Comment: @Toby Added A Quote for the question about cameras

Comment: Okay I made the question a bit more specific now - just take a look at the edit

Comment: @Toby All right, answered based on my experience. Don't forget to pick my answer as the right you if you feel like it did help you